# How do compare similar contents AND return a cell's contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, how do I tell it to compare two tables with SIMILAR primary keys, find a relatively close match, and then return the info from one of the cells (more than just a yes/no, 1/0, true/false.

For instance:
Table 1 has "ajacob44@email.com".  Table 2 has "ajacob".  What is the function(s) to have excel look through all of the contents in Table 2, find the close match, and then return "ajacob44@email.com"?  Or, if no close match is found, then something like "No match"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in Excel. However, the fuzzy lookup addin provided by Microsoft may help you to do what you want:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15011